# Numpy: Subtract Numpy argmin from 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I hope this isn't trivial, but I just can't seem to figure this out.  I would like to subtract the values with the lowest mean across an axis from a Numpy array.  I have a solution for a 2D case, but I'm having troubles with the indexing when trying to scale this to a 3D array

Here is an example of a working solution for a 2D array:

```
p = np.random.rand(5,4)
p 
Out[19]: array([[ 0.57606498,  0.91115162,  0.99684512,  0.19472954],
       [ 0.40138221,  0.27828228,  0.54265922,  0.34501819],
       [ 0.5818532 ,  0.57426127,  0.34042352,  0.92582929],
       [ 0.52050934,  0.2485581 ,  0.38900122,  0.80904034],
       [ 0.2481113 ,  0.90795755,  0.08984591,  0.87821432]])

# Determine which row has lowest mean value     
np.mean(p,axis=1)
Out[21]: array([ 0.66969782,  0.39183547,  0.60559182,  0.49177725,  0.53103227])

np.argmin(np.mean(p,axis=1))
Out[22]: 1

# Subtract the row with the lowest mean from all rows
p - p[1,:]
Out[23]: 
array([[ 0.17468277,  0.63286934,  0.4541859 , -0.15028865],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.18047099,  0.29597899, -0.2022357 ,  0.5808111 ],
       [ 0.11912713, -0.02972418, -0.153658  ,  0.46402215],
       [-0.15327091,  0.62967527, -0.45281331,  0.53319613]])

# This is the exact output I was expecting
```

What I have in reality are multiples of this 2D scenario with each array stacked along axis=2.  I'd like to do the same subtraction method for each index in axis=2, but I'm realizing that it's not as simple as just plugging in different axis values.

I can't seem to get past the following, or when I do get to a point where it doesn't throw an error, the results are still not what I expect:

```
p = np.random.rand(5,4,3)

p
Out[43]: 
array([[[ 0.23580937,  0.19305653,  0.86194822],
        [ 0.41709993,  0.44683942,  0.28430556],
        [ 0.76572705,  0.75579425,  0.79594985],
        [ 0.685063  ,  0.32461701,  0.68805631]],

       [[ 0.57820915,  0.42726291,  0.11445114],
        [ 0.73447151,  0.049985  ,  0.49230572],
        [ 0.98135938,  0.43760413,  0.13171786],
        [ 0.02386192,  0.70637415,  0.19299986]],

       [[ 0.29256757,  0.30444949,  0.82807243],
        [ 0.9626889 ,  0.83202173,  0.64797922],
        [ 0.8519458 ,  0.77007106,  0.88759858],
        [ 0.14843446,  0.70316647,  0.13061653]],

       [[ 0.78799308,  0.55117733,  0.46708366],
        [ 0.41660748,  0.87715813,  0.42998185],
        [ 0.70151952,  0.76968747,  0.0307918 ],
        [ 0.17334519,  0.91885418,  0.52401599]],

       [[ 0.92093943,  0.41441555,  0.30873481],
        [ 0.88212707,  0.6201796 ,  0.63563756],
        [ 0.20141727,  0.73164578,  0.70168395],
        [ 0.26550626,  0.44629422,  0.43902013]]])

minVals = np.argmin(np.mean(p,axis=1),axis=0)

# Subtract the values from the original
p-p[minVals,:,:]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-45-bcfd1b368acd>", line 1, in <module>
    p-p[minVals,:,:]

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,4,3) (3,4,3)
```

Is there a nice and efficient pythonic way of doing this without looping through each index?

### Update: Smaller 3D Array Example

Here is a 3x3x3 array.  The broadcast error goes away when switching to `axis=2`, but the results are not what I expect.

```
p = np.random.rand(3,3,3)

np.mean(p,axis=2)
Out[91]: 
array([[ 0.45775856,  0.83522052,  0.33993693],
       [ 0.76745111,  0.74376763,  0.34203944],
       [ 0.49303518,  0.58334377,  0.42269049]])

np.argmin(np.mean(p,axis=2),axis=0)

array([0, 2, 0], dtype=int64)

# the second row of the second dataset has the lowest mean and therefore I would expect this this row to be zeros
minVals = np.argmin(np.mean(p,axis=2),axis=0)

diff = p - p[minVals,:,:]

diff
Out[95]: 
array([[[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]],

       [[ 0.62609598,  0.2163244 , -0.0191726 ],
        [-0.02454002,  0.07961987,  0.42619174],
        [-0.7446807 ,  0.26103203,  0.24169552]],

       [[-0.06610852,  0.3830212 , -0.21108282],
        [ 0.21430653, -0.63997565, -0.32996113],
        [ 0.76924116, -0.36287242, -0.15810806]]])

diff[:,:,0]
Out[96]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.62609598, -0.02454002, -0.7446807 ],
       [-0.06610852,  0.21430653,  0.76924116]])

diff[:,:,1]
Out[97]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.2163244 ,  0.07961987,  0.26103203],
       [ 0.3830212 , -0.63997565, -0.36287242]])

diff[:,:,2]
Out[98]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [-0.0191726 ,  0.42619174,  0.24169552],
       [-0.21108282, -0.32996113, -0.15810806]])
```

I would expect the 3rd row of `diff[:,:,1]` to be zeros because:

```
np.argmin(np.mean(p,axis=2),axis=0)
array([0, 2, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: With `2D`, you are selecting the last axis with `axis=1` in `np.argmin(np.mean(p,axis=1))`. So, for `3D`  shouldn't that be `np.argmin(np.mean(p,axis=2),axis=1)` instead?

Comment: If I change it to `np.argmin(np.mean(p,axis=2),axis=1)` I no longer get the broadcast error, but the output is not what I would expect.  If I name the difference `subs` then the output for `subs[:,:,0]` has 2 rows that are zero when I would only expect one row to be zeros.

Comment: Maybe use a small 3D sample and show us the expected output? Or show us the loopy implementation?

Comment: `minVals` would be of shape `p.shape[1]`. But looking at the expected output, you are verifying by indexing into the third axis of output `diff[:,:,i]`. That part doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, not that trivial, but that appears to work:

```
p = np.arange(5*4*3).reshape((5, 4, 3))
```

So p is:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
    [ 3,  4,  5],
    [ 6,  7,  8],
    [ 9, 10, 11]],

   [[12, 13, 14],
    [15, 16, 17],
    [18, 19, 20],
    [21, 22, 23]],

   [[24, 25, 26],
    [27, 28, 29],
    [30, 31, 32],
    [33, 34, 35]],

   [[36, 37, 38],
    [39, 40, 41],
    [42, 43, 44],
    [45, 46, 47]],

   [[48, 49, 50],
    [51, 52, 53],
    [54, 55, 56],
    [57, 58, 59]]])
```

Calculating min rows:

```
m = np.mean(p, axis=2)
minrows = np.argmin(m, axis=1)
minrows.reshape((-1, 1, 1))
minrows
```

Shows:

```
array([[[0]],
   [[0]],
   [[0]],
   [[0]],
   [[0]]])
```

[Indexing p with arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays):

```
minidx = np.tile(minrows, (1, p.shape[1], p.shape[2]))
idx = np.indices(p.shape)
p - p[idx[0], minrows, idx[2]]
```

That shows:

```
array([[[0, 0, 0],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [6, 6, 6],
    [9, 9, 9]],

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [6, 6, 6],
    [9, 9, 9]],

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [6, 6, 6],
    [9, 9, 9]],

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [6, 6, 6],
    [9, 9, 9]],

   [[0, 0, 0],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [6, 6, 6],
    [9, 9, 9]]])
```

Which is the expected answer.

Comment: I've been playing around with this solution and I don't think it quite solves my problem.  I would expect `len(minrows) = p.shape[3]`.   I like to think of what I have as rows x column x layer.  I'd like to find the row[i]  with the lowest mean column value and do this for each layer.  Example if the rows with lowest mean are `minrows=[2,1,1]` then I would like to update the original as if i was to do this `p[:,:,0] =p[:,:,0] - p[minrow[0],:,0]`  `p[:,:,1] = p[:,:,1] - p[minrow[1],:,1]` etc.

Comment: As it is now the indexing is layer x row x column. To convince yourself, do the following: `p = np.random.rand(5,4,3); p; p[0,:,:]; p[0,0,:]`